# How put border bottom less than heading size

Tags: html, css

I want to add border at bottom of my heading but it will be less than heading width not 100% like i have attached a sample image.How it will be in CSS?
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqfLR.png)
[image]

Comment: you might be looking for  border-width: 50%; property.

Comment: That bottom border is incredibly faint.  I have to zoom into the image to even see a difference in the pixels

Comment: There's a border on that image?

Comment: @TheHeadRush i have add a new image please check it after zooming you will see border at the bottom of heading.